# Javascript error when reading large XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I am reading a large sitemap.xml file using the following code:

```
<div id="urls"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            loc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("loc");
            for(i=0;i<loc.length;i++) {
                document.getElementById("urls").appendChild(document.createTextNode( loc[i].firstChild.nodeValue ));
                document.getElementById("urls").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
            document.getElementById("urls").innerHTML = table;
        }       
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sitemap.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

</script>
```

When reading an XML file with more than 1000 lines it will error with the following details:

> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null (index):xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Any ideas on how I can get around this? Tried a few things which I have found online, but was unable to work it out properly.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must check whether `responseXML` is `null`. That happens if the XML file the server returned has parsing errors.

```
var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var locs, i, urls = document.getElementById("urls");

    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        if (this.responseXML) {
            locs = this.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("loc");

            for (i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
                urls.appendChild(document.createTextNode(locs[i].firstChild.nodeValue));
                urls.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }

            // What is that line? I've taken it from your code, but it can't be right.
            urls.innerHTML = table;
        } else {
            // responseXML is null if the response has XML parsing errors
            alert("The server did not send a proper sitemap file.");
        }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "sitemap.xml");
xmlhttp.send();
```

Also, as shown above, you should *really never* use synchronous requests. The whole point of having an event-handing callback function like `onreadystatechange` is to be able to make asynchronous requests.

There also is a big red warning on the MDN about that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#onreadystatechange

Lessons to learn:

1. Never use objects without a prior check if they are valid.
2. Never use synchronous HTTP requests from JavaScript.